# I have problem i cannot solve the python grouping problem

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping

How to write a code in Python language according to the following instructions:

1. Int values will be received from the user. When the user enters the value 0, the value retrieval process will be finished.
2. The entered values will be stored in an array.
3. Groups must have a minimum number of groups, with the sum of the elements of each group being less than 70
4. Groups will be printed on the screen.

I wrote but it is not working. What is the promblem of the code? Which part of the code should I edit?

```
aray = []
while True:
    a = int(input("Sayı gir:"))
    if a != 0:
        aray.append(a)
    else:
        break


x = 700

aray.sort(reverse=True)
aray2 = aray.copy()
array =[]

target = 700
groups = []
currentGroup = []
currentSum = 0

for number in fonk(x,aray,aray2):
    if currentSum + number <= target:
        currentGroup.append(number)
        currentSum += number
    else:
        groups.append(currentGroup)
        currentGroup = [number]
        currentSum = number

groups.append(currentGroup)

for group in groups:
    print("Group:")
    for num in group:
        print(num, end=" ")
    print()
    
def fonk(x,arr, aray2):
    count = 1
    min = 710
    for in1 in range(len(arr)):
        i = arr[in1]
        flag = False
        jj = 0
        for minfind in aray2:
            if minfind < min:
                min = minfind
        for j in aray2:
            if x >= j:
                flag = True
                jj = j
                aray2.remove(jj)
                break
        if not flag:
            continue
        if x >= jj:
            x -= jj
            array.append(jj)
            if x==0 or x<= min:
                x=700
                count+=1
            continue
        else: 
            x = 700
            count +=1
    
    return array
```

Inputs:

```
400
10
700
200
600
490
160
300
200
320
```

My Outputs:

```
Group:
700
Group:
600
Group:
490 200
Group:
400 300
Group:
320 200 160
Group:
100
```

But the output should be:

```
700
600 100
490 200
400 300
320 200 160
```

Comment: Did you put those instructions through a translation service? Point 3 doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: I hope it is more understandable.

Comment: Should point 3 read *"Result must have a minimum number of groups, with the sum of the elements of each group being at most 700"*?

Comment: Using `aray`, `aray2` and `array` as names for variables is bad enough. What is even worse is that the objects named with them are not [`arrays`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), but [`lists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Comment: "Groups must have a minimum number of groups" still doesn't make sense, but basically I assume that you need the minimal number of groups to contain each entered value, such that all entered values are in a group that doesn't exceed a sum of 70. It's basically a "knapsack"/"bin-packing" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a greedy implementation: https://reintech.io/blog/python-bin-packing-problem-guide.

- Like you already figured out, you need to sort the list first.
- Afterwards, you add each number to the first group it fits in, creating new groups when necessary.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

MAX_SUM = 7

numbers: list[int] = []
while True:
    number = int(input("Number:"))
    if not number:
        break

    numbers.append(number)

numbers.sort(reverse=True)
groups: list[list[int]] = []
for number in numbers:
    for group in groups:
        if sum(group) + number <= MAX_SUM:
            group.append(number)
            break
    else:
        groups.append([number])

for group in groups:
    print(*group)
```

- `for group in groups`: `group` is a reference here, that when modified updates the corresponding group in `groups`
- `sum(group)`: `sum` calculates the sum of the numbers in the `group`
- `for...else`: the `else` block gets executed if the loop completes its iterations without encountering a `break` statement.
- `print(*group)`: the `*` operator unpack the numbers from the `group` passing the as arguments to the `print` function

As @Unmitigated pointed out, it's greedy, so it doesn't work for `[3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]`:

```
3 3
2 2 2
2
```

Expected:

```
3 2 2
3 2 2
```

Non-greedy implementation (using itertools):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from itertools import permutations

MAX_SUM = 7

numbers: list[int] = []
while True:
    number = int(input("Number:"))
    if not number:
        break

    numbers.append(number)

numbers.sort(reverse=True)
groups = [[number] for number in numbers]
for permutation in permutations(numbers):
    candidate: list[list[int]] = []
    for number in permutation:
        for group in candidate:
            if sum(group) + number <= MAX_SUM:
                group.append(number)
                break
        else:
            candidate.append([number])
            if len(candidate) >= len(groups):
                break

    if len(groups) > len(candidate):
        groups = candidate

for group in groups:
    print(*group)
```

- `[[number] for number in numbers]`: this puts every number in a separate group.
- `for permutation in permutations(numbers)`: this iterates over all permutations of `numbers`.

Comment: The greedy solution is wrong for this problem. Your code outputs 3 groups for `MAX_SUM = 10` and `numbers = [6, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2]`, but the correct solution uses only two groups: `[6, 2, 2]` and `[5, 3, 2]`.

Comment: @Unmitigated, I've added a non-greedy implementation.